# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, date, pymongo

I have to do a post method to insert some dates in mongoDb using pymongo.
I gotto to pass a dd/mm/yyyy in payload, something like this 12/05/2018 and convert to insert in mongo as Iso

```
data = 12/05/2018
data = datetime.strptime(data_, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

But mongo is storing date like bellow

"Sat, 12 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT",

Comment: Are you trying to get the database to store timestamp?

Comment: I had solved it

Comment: If you've already solved it, you can add your answer to your question to help out other developers.